# Issue with string.lower in lua code with cyrillic (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: luatex, cyrillic

The `string.lower` function Lua does not work with Cyrillic. How to fix it?

[image]

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\def\ptestcyr{%
\directlua{
tex.print(string.lower("Supervisory Control And Data Acquisition"),"\string\\newline")
tex.print(string.lower("Ямало-Ненецкий Автономный Округ"))
}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\ptestcyr
\end{document}
```

Comment: that is a lua question, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860127/11796366. In LaTeX I would use `\MakeLowercase{Ямало-Ненецкий Автономный Округ}`. Unrelated but don't use `Renderer=Basic`, that is really basic and used in math.

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to LaTeX. If you run `print(string.lower("Привет Мир"))` with Lua, it doesn't work. I think you write your own Lua function to do this.

Comment: In order for string.lower to work with Cyrillic, you need to set the Russian locale by calling os.setlocale. If you have a Russian-language OS, it is enough to call os.setlocale("") with an empty locale name - the default locale of the OS will be substituted. But it doesn't work in LuaLaTeX. Thanks @Ulrike Fischer.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Fraiman.

Comment: I'm not sure Yamalia residents would like to see the name of their Okrug lowercased though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can write your own Tim Toady function.

Based on `utf8data` that you can download from https://github.com/artemshein/luv/blob/master/utf8data.lua and some code found in https://github.com/Stepets/utf8.lua/issues/13:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{luacode}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\begin{luacode}
require("utf8data")
function timtowtdilower(str_in)
  local lc_str = str_in:gsub(utf8.charpattern,utf8_uc_lc)
  return lc_str
end
\end{luacode}
\def\ptestcyr{%
\directlua{
tex.print(string.lower("Supervisory Control And Data Acquisition"),"\string\\newline")
tex.print(timtowtdilower("Ямало-Ненецкий Автономный Округ"))
}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\ptestcyr
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the font is different because I don't have Times New Roman installed.

Comment: Thanks, @Marijn.